# How to perform SELECT where a column must match ALL values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Consider a table with 3 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
ItemName nvarchar(100),
ItemRank int,
ItemLoc nvarchar(100))
```

Example output from the table (query to insert below)

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
```

> 1. Item1, 1, LocA
> 2. Item1, 2, LocB
> 3. Item1, 3, LocC
> 4. Item2, 1, LocA
> 5. Item2, 2, LocC
> 6. Item3, 1, LocB

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[myTable]
           ([ItemName]
           ,[ItemRank]
           ,[ItemLoc])
     VALUES
           ('Item1',1,'LocA'),
           ('Item1',2,'LocB'),
           ('Item1',3,'LocC'),
           ('Item2',1,'LocA'),
           ('Item2',2,'LocC'),
           ('Item3',1,'LocB')
```

Now, I know that there are only 3 possible `ItemLoc` values (LocA, LocB, LocC).

I need to select all `ItemName`s from `myTable` where the item does not have all `ItemLoc`s assigned (those being LocA, LocB, LocC).

The desired output using aboce data is

> 1. Item2
> 2. Item3

since `Item2` does not have `LocB` set, and `Item3` does not have `LocA` or `LocC` set.

How can I do that? I tried using `NOT EXISTS` query and listing the conditions, but to no avail.

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use aggregation

```
select ItemName
from myTable
where ItemLoc in ('LocA','LocB','LocC')
group by ItemName
having count(distinct itemloc)<3
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this should also guard against someone putting incorrect `ItemLoc` there - but it seems your edit takes care of that. Thanks!